# cmd.ExecuteScalar() returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I want to get the count of rows of a table.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ))";
Records = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

even if there is 1 row in employee table,  Records always have value 0.
why ExecuteScalar() returns 0?

Comment: Why all the nested FROM clauses? What happens if you just use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to calculate is the number of rows in the EMPLOYEE table, therefore Pranav and Vinod are right. But assuming you try to simplify your situation just to point directly to your problem, I would say that you need to give names to your temporary tables like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ) as T1) as T2";
Records = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

That should do the trick.

One additional suggestion is not to use count(0); instead use count(0). '*' brings all data in the view; which is an unnecessary performance decrement for count function.

Answer (score 1):

It returns 0 because your SQL request isn't valid.

You should **always** try your requests directly against your database (for instance using SQL Server Management Studio if you are using SQL Server) before writing them in your code. You would have seen it doesn't return anything because it has a syntax error.

If you want to use nested `SELECT * FROM` as you wrote, here's the valid SQL request that will return what you expected:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ) AS Foo1 ) AS Foo2
```

In any case, as all other answers have noted, this doesn't make much sense, and must be replaced by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE"; 
int Records = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

That should return the number of rows in the EMPLOYEE table.

To double check, use the SQL management studio to execute the same code against your SQL server and see what the result is.  Is it possible that your application is configured to point a different database to the one that you are viewing?

Answer (score 0):

Just say:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE";
Records = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE"
Int record=(Int32)cmd.Executescalar();
```